# Migradoc real table cell padding

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

Is there a way to add real padding to migradoc table cells? The options that they currently have (LeftPadding and RightPadding) actually work like margins and not like padding. And if you use it, it pushes the background color as well instead of pushing the content only.

This is what happens when you add "padding" to the whole row or individual cells (added it to the first row):

[image]

By default it looks like this:

[image]

If you wish to remove the white space between the columns, it seems like you have to do it by setting these padding properties to 0 and then you get this:

[image]

..which is almost what I want, but I want to push the content of the cell a bit to towards the centre of the cell from all 4 sides so that it looks like this and has a little room to "breathe":

[image]

It was even [asked on their forums](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=812) a long time ago about whether this could be done, but the answer doesn't solve the issue at all. It simply mentions the padding properties which work the exact opposite way of what the OP in that thread asked for (which is the same thing I want to do).

I'm using PDFsharp-MigraDoc-gdi v1.50.4000-beta3b nuget package.

Any ways to hack around this odd behaviour? Thanks.

*EDIT: updated with a piece of code I use and with added bit recommended by PDFsharp Novice*

```
var table = new Table();
var columnCount = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
{
    table.AddColumn();
}

var hedingRow= table.AddRow();
hedingRow.Format.Font.Bold = true;
hedingRow.Format.Font.Color = Color.Parse("0xFFFFFFFF");
hedingRow.Format.Shading.Color = Color.Parse("0xFF005aa0");
hedingRow.HeadingFormat = true;
hedingRow.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Field");
hedingRow.Cells[1].AddParagraph("Type");
hedingRow.Cells[2].AddParagraph("Default");
hedingRow.Cells[3].AddParagraph(String.Empty);

// Doesn't work as I would assume it should based on PDFsharp Novice
hedingRow.Cells[0].Format.LeftIndent = 4;
hedingRow.Cells[0].Format.RightIndent = 4;
hedingRow.Cells[0].Format.Shading.Color = Color.Parse("0xFF005aa0");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the background color for the cell and/or for the text in the cell.

If you set the color for the cell, the padded area will also have the color.

If you set the color the text only, the padded area will have no color.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I'm still not getting the desired result. I updated my question with a code sample, could you please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Skip the `Format` - that applies to the text. Try `hedingRow.Shading.Color = Color.Parse("0xFF005aa0");` or `hedingRow.Cells[0].Shading.Color = Color.Parse("0xFF005aa0");` to set the color of the row or the cell (incl. the padding).

Comment: That's great, it fixed it. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks a lot. :) cheers!